# What does this screen mean?

Tags: error-correction, google-sites

I attempted to go to google sites to create a website for my aerospace company and I got this: [image: screen]
does anyone have anything that could help or get rid of it? (If it is of any help, I am using google chrome on a Lenovo 300E laptop) My problem is, I see this pure white screen (above) and no matter how many times I hit refresh, it never lets me go through. My #1 problem with this is that it probably means there is something wrong with the computer, since I was able to go to this website before, and now I can't. I'm really frustrated and I would like some help or advice, or just something helpful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not a *purely* white screen. It says "reset".

1. Right-click anywhere in that window and select "View page source". Do you see anything giving an indication of the problem?
2. There may be an error with the cached version of the page you're viewing. Close Chrome and re-open it, but don't browse to that page. Just open it to Google search or something.

Now, on the upper-right of the screen there's a "3-dot" menu (3 vertical dots). Click on that. Click on "Settings", then "Privacy and security".

Click on "Clear browsing data" and put a checkmark in all 3 boxes and select "All time" for the "Time range". Click "Clear data".

Close the browser and open it once again and browse to the site you were trying to view. If all is well it should work.